# encrypt paypal buy now button html form

Tags: php, html, forms, encryption, paypal

I've a classic paypal buynow button form in html. I need to encrypt the form to hide the parameters like amount or seller email data...

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="+++++++++">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="IT">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="DESCRIPTION">
<input type="hidden" name="os0" value="PAYMENT OBJECT n.<?php echo $_SESSION["ordernumber"]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="PAYMENT ORDER n. <?php echo $_SESSION["ordernumber"]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="VSTCB">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $topaypal; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="www.++++++.com/ok.php">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/IT/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal è il metodo rapido e sicuro per pagare e farsi pagare online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I've my private key and public certificate generated with openssl, and I've also the cert_Id of paypal and the relative paypal_public_certificate, but I'm not able at all to encrypt my html form, I've only found this command line on paypal site:

"**PPEncrypt CertFile PrivKeyFile PPCertFile InputFile OutputFile**"

Ther reference page for these information is on the paypal site at the address:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/

but I don't know how to use it...

does anyone know how to encrypt the form using the command line provided by paypal, a kind of step by step guide if it's possible?

many regards helping me

Comment: Use TLS. Let your certificate sign by a trusted CA and install it in your web server (Apache, nginx, IIS, etc.). Anything else does not provide any security.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by "encrypting" these parameters? They will inevitably be visible to the user when they check out…

Comment: @duskwuff I need to encrypt the content parameters of the above html form like amount... I know there is a method to encrypt the code for manually created paypal button. I should use the paypal "EWP software Manually Created Buttons" to do this and obtain something like this <form action=......... method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
MIIHPwY.….BOu+vkC1g+HRToc=
-----END PKCS7-----">

Answer (score 0):

The command line "`PPEncrypt CertFile PrivKeyFile PPCertFile InputFile OutputFile`" breaks down to the following components:

- `PPEncrypt`  - PayPal's encryption algorithm
- `CertFile`   - The pathname to your own public certificate
- `PKCS12File` - The pathname to the PKCS12-format of your own public certificate
- `PPCertFile` - The pathname to a copy of the PayPal public certificate
- `Password`   - The passphrase to the PKCS12-format of your own public certificate
- `InputFile`  - The pathname to file containing the non-encrypted Website Payments HTML Form variables
- `OutputFile` - A file name for the encrypted output
  [Sandbox]   The optional word Sandbox that lets you test payment buttons in the PayPal Sandbox that you protected with Encrypted Website Payments

However, you may want to opt for a [**button hosted by PayPal**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/#button-hosting), as hosting means that you won't have to re-generate the certificates each time the form parameters are updated.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thank you @Obsidian Age I've already found this on paypal site but I'm not able to find a guide to implement the command line "PPEncrypt CertFile PrivKeyFile PPCertFile InputFile OutputFile".   I should use the paypal "EWP software for Manually Created Buttons" to do this and obtain something like this <form action=......... method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7----- MIIHPwY.…......BOu+vkC1g+HRToc= -----END PKCS7-----"> After downloading the EWP software  for Windows how can I encrypt my HTML code of the button form using the ""PPEncrypt..." command line